# Mutli-regional persistent disk with GKE in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage, kubernetes-pvc

I understand we can mount persistent disks with containers created inside clusters. GCP offers us **Regional persistent disks (standard and SSD)** which is nothing but keeping a disk in two zones in one single region.

For example:

***Disk-A*** is present in ***us-central1-a*** as well as a copy is maintained in ***us-central1-b***. This way we can be sure that in case a zone goes down, we can shift our workload to another zone. This simply makes sure of High Availability in one region (e.g ***asia-south1***) and multiple zones (e.g ***asia-south1-a*** and ***asia-south1-b***) inside that region.

I am looking for a way to have multi-regional disks. I understand it is highly unlikely that the entire region will go down.

What are the ways to this? I have spent some time on Google but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this feature is not available at this moment, I went ahead and forwarded the use case to the GKE product team and also created a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/142536825) for you to track the issue. Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue. I'm unable to provide you with an E.T.A. or guarantee that this feature will be deployed. Nevertheless, rest assured that your feedback is always taken seriously.

Comment: Thank you, I understand multi-regional disks are not supported with GCP yet. However, we can make use of distributed file systems like Ceph, etc. I am looking for other ways to do the same.

Comment: At the point of GCP, its a feature request, and currently, it is not possible to have multi-regional disks. I'm not sure how Ceph is working, but you can use your methods.